# laravel-8 CRUD operation not working perfectly

Tags: laravel-8

Here I am doing a laravel CRUD operation where insert and delete work perfectly but the update is not working. Can you explain this?.

You can see if I click the edit button it`s opening my edit.blade.php
[image]

after changing data if I click the update button it shows scoreupdate updates successfully but the value is not changing.

Thin is my index.blade.php

```
{{-- edit modal --}}
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Score Update</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="modal_body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').on('click', '.edit', function() {
            let subcat_id = $(this).data('id');
            $.get("scoreupdates/edit/" + subcat_id, function(data) {
                $("#modal_body").html(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my ScoreupdateController.php

```
public function edit($id)
    {
            $data=Scoreupdate::find($id);

            return view('admin.manage.scoreupdate.edit',compact('data'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Query Bulder
            $data=array();
            $data['out_type']=$request->out_type;
            $data['out_by_type']=$request->out_by_type;
            $data['one']=$request->one;
            $data['two']=$request->two;
            $data['three']=$request->three;
            $data['four']=$request->four;
            $data['six']=$request->six;
            $data['wide']=$request->wide;
            $data['no_ball']=$request->no_ball;
            $data['bye']=$request->bye;
            $data['leg_bye']=$request->leg_bye;
            $data['penalty_runs']=$request->penalty_runs;
            DB::table('scoreupdates')->where('id',$request->id)->update($data);

        $notification = array('message'=>'Scoreupdates Updated!','alert-type'=>'success');
        return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
    }
```

This is my Scoreupdate.php model

```
class Scoreupdate extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=['out_type','out_by_type','one','two','three','four','six',
                        'wide','no_ball','bye','leg_bye','penalty_runs'];
}
```

This is my route admin.php

```
// scoreupdates route
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'scoreupdates'],function(){
        Route::get('/','ScoreupdateController@index')->name('scoreupdates.index');
        Route::post('/store','ScoreupdateController@store')->name('scoreupdates.store');
        Route::get('/delete/{id}','ScoreupdateController@destroy')->name('scoreupdates.delete');
        Route::get('/edit/{id}','ScoreupdateController@edit');
        Route::post('/update','ScoreupdateController@update')->name('scoreupdates.update');
    });
```

This is my edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('scoreupdates.update') }}" method="Post">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="out_type">out_type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="out_type" value="{{ $data->out_type }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you out_type</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="out_by_type">out_by_type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="out_by_type" value="{{ $data->out_by_type }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="one">One</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="one" value="{{ $data->one }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="two">Two</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="two" value="{{ $data->two }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="three">Three</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="three" value="{{ $data->three }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="four">Four</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="four" value="{{ $data->four }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="six">Six</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="six" value="{{ $data->six }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="wide">Wide</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wide" value="{{ $data->wide }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="no_ball">No ball</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_ball" value="{{ $data->no_ball }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="bye">Bye</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bye" value="{{ $data->bye }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="leg_bye">Leg Bye</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="leg_bye" value="{{ $data->leg_bye }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="penalty_runs">Penalty runs</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="penalty_runs" value="{{ $data->penalty_runs }}" required="">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="from-text text-muted">This is you score name</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Everything looks fine to me but I guess the ID attribute in request is probably NULL. In your controller try ```dd($request);``` and see if ID is indeed NULL or not.